# looking for Python for-loop or while-loop which is able to iterates through columns in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop, while-loop

```
m=[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
names=[lev, yan, coke , coke, yan, lev, lev, yan, lev, yan, lev, yan, coke, coke, coke, lev, yan, lev, lev, yan, coke]
n=[1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

I am looking for an iterative loop that adds up values of column n if the value in column m is non-zero.

For example, at the 3rd place of column m, the value is 1 (non-zero) so it should add in the column n from index 0 to 2 i.e. 1+1+3=5. Similarly, at m[6]=3 (non-zero) this implies 4+1+1+2=8 and so on for distinct names in the names column so that it takes on name time and do the above iteration.

Here is my code:

```
starting_idx = 0 
sum_lst = [] 
for idx, val in enumerate(m): 
    if val != 0: 
        sum_lst.append(sum(n[starting_idx: (idx+1)])) 
        starting_idx = idx+1 
    elif val==0: 
        sum_lst.append(0) 
print(sum_lst)
```

Comment: What is your expected form of output? In addition, it would be better if you provide your code. Your code is not a form of dataframe.

Comment: Hi, please use code-formatting to make your code easier to read. Also, as @SangkeunPark mentioned, please give us the expected form of output

Comment: ''' starting_idx = 0
sum_lst = []
for idx, val in enumerate(m):
    if val != 0:
        sum_lst.append(sum(n[starting_idx: (idx+1)]))
        starting_idx = idx+1
    elif val==0:
        sum_lst.append(0)
print(sum_lst) '''
Need to extend it for names column where it iterate through names column and do it for each name separately

Comment: how do you add names? you need to include your full desired outcome from the given input here

Comment: For example for name lev it should be like and similarly for each name
Names=[lev, lev, lev, lev, lev, lev, lev, lev, lev, lev, lev, lev]
m=[0, 0, 2,0, 3, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
n=[1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 7, 13, 20, 1, 2, 1, 4]
Result=[0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 7, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28]

Comment: It would be better to clarify what ouput you exactly want to get on the question box.

Comment: Check above comment where I have given the required solution. I am new here I don't know how to write it in the right format. @sangkeun Park